# Spring AOP: Adding advice in a running application

Tags: spring, spring-aop

How can I add or remove [Spring AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Aspect-oriented_programming_framework) proxies in a running application without restarting the server?

Something like this

```
    GenericApplicationContext ctx = new GenericApplicationContext();
    BeanDefinitionBuilder promotion4Advice = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Promotion4Action.class).addPropertyValue("discountPercentage", 0.5);
    promotion4Advice.addPropertyValue("discountCode", 16);
    promotion4Advice.addPropertyValue("discountComment", "50% on regular item");
    ctx.registerBeanDefinition("promotion4Advice", promotion4Advice.getBeanDefinition());

    BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(ProxyFactoryBean.class);
    builder.addPropertyValue("proxyTargetClass", true);
    builder.addPropertyValue("interceptorNames", new String[] {"promotion4Advice"});
    ctx.registerBeanDefinition("proxyFactoryBean", builder.getBeanDefinition());
```

My XML config looks like this:

```
<bean id="promotion4Advice"
    class="com.promotion.actions.Promotion4Action">
    <property name="discountPercentage" value="0.5" />
    <property name="discountCode" value="16" />
    <property name="discountComment" value="50% on regular item" />
</bean>
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:aspect id="promotion4Aspect" ref="promotion4Advice">
        <aop:pointcut id="promotion4PointCut"
            expression="execution(* com.controller.ShoppingBagController.defaultHandler(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) and args(request)" />

        <aop:before pointcut-ref="promotion4PointCut" method="applyPromotion4"
            arg-names="request" />
    </aop:aspect>
    <aop:aspect id="promotion4Aspect1" ref="promotion4Advice">
        <aop:pointcut id="promotion4PointCut1"
            expression="execution(* com.controller.ReviewOrderController.handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) and args(request)" />

        <aop:before pointcut-ref="promotion4PointCut1" method="interceptOrderDetails"
            arg-names="request" />
    </aop:aspect>
    <aop:aspect id="promotion4Aspect4" ref="promotion4Advice">
        <aop:pointcut id="promotion4PointCut4"
            expression="execution(* com.controller.ShoppingBagController.applyPromoCode(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, String, String)) and args(request, promoCode, mappedURL)" />

        <aop:after pointcut-ref="promotion4PointCut4" method="interceptPromoCode"
            arg-names="request,promoCode,mappedURL" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

This is one of the promotions... Like the above i have 3 other and want to be able to configure these dynamically through aop without changing the xml and restarting the server. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, mainly because Spring wires beans during context startup. This means if bean `A` is injected into bean `B` and the former one is not wrapper with any proxy, it will be injected directly.

Now of course you can take `A`, wrap it in a proxy and put it back in the container (as a copy `A'`). But `B` does not know about `A'` at all.

If your know in advance which beans are subject to dynamic adding/removing aspects, wrap them eagerly in aspect that does nothing on startup (e.g. calling sort of `NoOpStrategy`). When you need to "add" the aspect, just change that strategy to something else.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz for your reply but just to reiterate what you mean.. for example if i have supposedly 4 types of promotion aspects acting on same pointcut(which is a frontcontroller) and want to apply or remove them dynamically. I need to do what ? Sorry for ignorance... didn't understand the "NoOpStrategy"

Comment: @Abhi: I think he means that you have to have static pointcuts _and_ have at least one aspect (possibly trivial) applied at each of those pointcuts during bean creation. This is to force Spring to insert the aspect-handling machinery between your code and the “outer shell” of the bean, so that when you come to add more aspects, everything is already set for those aspects to plug into.

Comment: +1 BTW for an elegant solution that's got at least a good chance of working.