# Dynamic AOP configuration in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm new to Spring AOP, and I've to know if it's possible to implement my project with Spring AOP. Specifically, I want to know if in Spring AOP it's possible to configure, at runtime, which aspects will be executed and in which order. NB: I want to control only mine application aspects', without interfering with Spring-managed aspects like transactions or security.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the ordering of aspesct (using declare precedence), but its hard to do this at run time, as it would need to reapply the weaving for already weaved classes.
The same goes for specifying which aspects to execute.

You could have an if(!enabled){return;} check at the start of each aspect method, and the enabled flag could be set on or off just like any normal bean.  This way, the aspects are always weaved in, but they will do nothing if they are disabled.

**UPDATE**

Here is example of how to use an aspect as a bean.
Lets say you have an aspect like this:

```
@Component // IMPORTANT
public aspect MyAspect {
    Object responder;

    public void setResponder(Object object) {
        this.responder=object;
    }
}
```

Then in your spring service class, you can wiring the aspect like this:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Autowired
    MyAspect aspect;

    void action() {
        aspect.setResponder(null);
    }
}
```

This works because aspects are actually java classes.  The component annotation causes the aspect to be recognised as a bean by the spring component scan.
I have compiled this code successfully, but not actually tested it runtime, so would be good to know if it works.

Comment: I've found a possible solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235359/spring-aop-adding-advice-in-a-running-application?rq=1. It says to load `NoOpAdvices` at startup, and substitute them with desired advices when needed. Do you think it's applicable? How can I do this in an application server, where i must control aspects in function of incoming requests?

Comment: I think that is effectively the same as what I was suggesting.
The aspects should be predefined and static.  The work aspect does can be dynamic.
Aspects are normal spring beans, so you can control them as you would any other bean.

Comment: From Spring Documentation, in the AOP section, I've founded the `Ordered` interface, that declare the `int getvalue()` method, with which I can control Aspect's ordering (just let them implement the interface). Now I have two questions: 1) will the `getValue()` return value modify aspect behavior at runtime, after initialization? 2) If I apply @Service and @Aspect annotations at a class, will the @Service instance be the same of @Aspect? If not, how can I retrieve from an object a reference to the Aspect instance used by the system?

Comment: Is `@Aspect` annotation unnecessary? Or should I use both `@Aspect` and `@Component`? Does it work at runtime? And what about ordering?

Comment: There are different ways to define aspects. @Aspect annotation is for annotation style aspects.  My example is strongly typed aspectj style.  read more here: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj.html

Comment: Sorry, I've not noticed the `public aspect MyAspect` declaration, I was reading like `public class MyAspect`.

Comment: Unfortunately, even through `Ordered` interface setting advice's order is not possible during execution, since order is configured only one time at initialization. `NoOpAdvice`s managing is the only solution.